# add error bars to two plots that are overlapped (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a problem with a plot made with two different data frames. What I need is to graph the error bars, which come from  different data sets.

The first data frame:

```
dput(resudospobl)

structure(list(Poblacion = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("Carolina", 
"Lavalle"), class = "factor"), sexo = 
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("hembra", "macho"), 
class = "factor"), N = c(960, 
960, 640, 640), IR = 
c(0.627976287904167, 
0.591445531573958, 
0.752046236173437, 0.748963332945312), 
sd = c(0.241332559805011, 
0.24103347180023, 0.194890181966294, 
0.20467196068143), se = 
c(0.00778897487518677, 
0.00777932185134039, 0.007703710857727, 
0.00809036961157182), 
ci = c(0.0152854016885121, 
0.0152664582011643, 0.0151276489859234, 
0.0158869243550959)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Second data frame:

```
dput(resudospobl2)

structure(list(Poblacion = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label 
= c("Carolina", 
"Lavalle"), class = "factor"), Trat 
= structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("manzana", "uva"), 
class = "factor"), N = c(960, 
960, 640, 640), IR = 
c(0.658423422891667, 
0.560998396586458, 
0.758180928170312, 
0.742828640948437), sd = 
c(0.21174136546939, 
0.259656138696281, 
0.20285509360085, 
0.196492580813269), se = 
c(0.00683392318471805, 
0.00838036584092683, 
0.00801855163431666, 
0.00776705123368289
), ci = c(0.0134111693336726, 
0.0164459714183095, 
0.0157458965866789, 
0.0152520294295554)), row.names = 
c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

where se is standard error. My attempt is:

```
 ggplot()+
  #first layer
  geom_point(data=resudospobl, 
  aes(x=Poblacion, y=IR, colour=sexo) , 
  shape="square", size= 3)+
  #second layer
  geom_point(data=resudospobl2, 
  aes(x=Poblacion, y=IR, colour=Trat), 
  size=3)+
  #error bars
  geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl , aes( 
  ymin=IR-se, ymax=IR+se), size=0.3, 
  width=.1)+
  geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl2 , aes( 
  ymin=IR-se, ymax=IR+se), size=0.3, 
  width=.1)
```

The result is an error message. The plot without the error bars is the following, with two populations grouped by sex and treatment:

[image: theres two populations, grouped by sex and treatment]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key part of the error message is `object 'x' not found`.  Because you don't define the variable for the x axis globally in `ggplot()`, you need to do so in the `geom_errorbar()` layers so ggplot knows where to place the error bars along the x axis.  Add `x = Poblacion` within `aes()`.

Comment: wow! thanks for answer so quickly , that fixed the error thanks!

Comment: @aosmith Please post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the error message is `object 'x' not found`.

You didn't define an `x` variable globally in `ggplot()`.  Since you also didn't pass one to `geom_errorbar()`, ggplot can't plot the error bars because it doesn't know where to put them on the x axis.

Your options are to put `x` in each error bar layer:

```
ggplot()+
     geom_point(data=resudospobl, 
                aes(x=Poblacion, y=IR, colour=sexo) , 
                shape="square", size= 3)+
     geom_point(data=resudospobl2, 
                aes(x=Poblacion, y=IR, colour=Trat), 
                size=3)+
     geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl , aes(x = Poblacion,
          ymin=IR-se, ymax=IR+se), size=0.3, 
          width=.1)+
     geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl2 , aes(x = Poblacion,
          ymin=IR-se, ymax=IR+se), size=0.3, 
          width=.1)
```

OR, because you use the same `x`, `y`, `ymin`, and `ymax` variables for all layers for both datasets you can set these globally in `ggplot()` instead of separately in each layer.

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=Poblacion, y=IR, ymin=IR-se, ymax=IR+se))+
     geom_point(data=resudospobl, 
                aes(colour=sexo) , 
                shape="square", size= 3)+
     geom_point(data=resudospobl2, 
                aes(colour=Trat), 
                size=3)+
     geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl, size=0.3, 
                   width=.1)+
     geom_errorbar(data=resudospobl2, size=0.3, 
                   width=.1)
```